# Align echoed data to top right of page

Tags: html, css, positioning

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("Logxxxom", "Lxxxc", "axxx!", "Lxxxc");
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $table = $row[0];
    echo '<h3>', $table, '</h3>';
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    if ($result1) {
        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
        $column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
        echo '<tr>';
        while ($row3 = $column->fetch_row()) {
            echo '<th>' . $row3[0] . '</th>';


        }
        echo '</tr>';
        while ($row2 = $result1->fetch_row()) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row2 as $key => $value) {
                echo '<td>', $value, '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table><br />';
    }
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I need this code aligned to the top right corner of the page.. Kind of stumped??? Any suggestions would be appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds more like an html / css problem than a php problem. You should post the generated html instead of the php.

Comment: and the css code is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align to top and right the content (only the table) you have to put this on the **< head >** and **< /head >** tags of you php file:

```
<style>
.db-table {position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Good Deal... Only I need center right. This is extreme right..

Comment: I got it now!!! Thanks Bro your #1!!     ;top:100px;right:100px;

Comment: One more question, I have 2 tables being echoed one on top of the other table. Is there any way that I can space the two tables apart??  Ill post pic soon

Comment: Try with padding-top and padding-bottom, on the TD something like that:
<td style="padding-top:10px;padding.bottom:10px;"></td>

Comment: What do you have send? xD
Upload it to imgur.com for example ;)

Comment: postimg org/image/wwu7duhaz

Comment: you have to put the period between the postimg and org

Comment: echo '<td style="padding-top:10px;padding.bottom:10px;">',$value,'</td>';

Comment: After updating code I have space between rows vertically.... If I could only space then horizontally.

Comment: I just changed my sql statement to this and it seem to be working better.. Thanks

Comment: $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table where online = 1 LIMIT 0,9");

Comment: Every thing is all good now, This ticket is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser has no idea of what PHP is, all it sees is HTML, CSS and Javascript. If you need help about formatting your webpage, you need to ask your question with the HTML/CSS tags.

If you don't understand that PHP is back-end and has nothing to do with how your page is displayed, you might want to hit the books.

PHP will echo the HTML code you ask it to echo, this HTML code that you echo is what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning for your table but do take into account that absolute positioning is highly dependent upon parent containers which means that the following code might work only if your table has no positioned elements between it and the `<body>` element (otherwise the element that has a position declared will act as a positioning parent to the table).

Just add the following selector to your CSS code:

```
.top-right-aligned {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

and change your PHP line to look like this

```
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table right-aligned">';
```

If you can't make changes to the table's parent containers which potentially have defined positioning you could also use fixed positioning but that approach might also come with some side effects.

```
.top-right-aligned {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a very good solution to my issue... Ill let you know how it work out!!